# Secure Portable Mail Client

Tags: email

I want to store all my email on a portable client on a USB drive if possible. My aim is to protect the stick with an encryption if possible so that if I remove the USB stick all traces should be gone.

- Is this a possible scenario including all the trace removal upon disconnection of the USB drive?
- If no, why not?

Comment: “Secure” on its own is meaningless. Secure **against what**?

Comment: Hello ladies, I've reformatted the question. @gilles thank you for the reminder

Comment: It's not enough that the mail client uses encrypted storage. You must also make sure that the client either locks its memory or the swap space is encrypted too.

Comment: Asking for a recommendation for a specific product is offtopic, since it is not a good fit for SE sites. The rest of the question could be reopened, if you address @Gilles's comment. Specifically, I think this is an example of an XY question - why are you assuming this is a good solution? Instead ask about your problem, and see if this solution actually fits that.

Comment: @avid cab you help me refining the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use a portable mail client (e.g. [Thunderbird Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/thunderbird_portable)) store it on a portable device and encrypt the device with something like [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) to store your e-mail related files in an encrypted container.

As to whether this is a secure solution, that all depends on what you mean by secure.  Encrypting the local files relating to your e-mail should provide a degree of security from attacks like people finding the encrypted USB stick and trying to read your mail, however it likely wouldn't protect you fully from using the client on a compromised computer as the stick has to be decrypted when you use it.

Comment: I see. Still the usage of a portable client would be enough for me. Without the password the client would be  secure.